# Apple's universal logging, it's a silly thing but import os vs import os.log?

Tags: swift, logging, universal

I use universal logging and this has been bugging me for a while. Many developers I know as well as and various blogs all tell me to `import os.log`.

However I think that's wrong because:

- Apple's recommendation on imports is to import the top level module only. ie. `import os`.
- When I look at the headers all the functions and types are in the `os` header and the `os.log` header only contains a few lower level types. Not the full framework.

So why does `import os.log` even work? I'm not an expert on this but I think due to the way imports work in C `import os.log` is effectively pulling in the `os` header and in turn all the other headers it imports. Thereby making the full framework available.

Some developers have told me that I should `import os.log` because `os' is not clear enough and some have even told me it contains other "Operating System" things. But I've found not evidence of that.

So, the question is - any I right in only using `import os`? Or is there some other reason to  `import os.log` I've not found?

Comment: I've been wondering the same... further one could use `import OSLog' that seems to work the same way as 'import os.log', or not?

Comment: I use 'import OSLog' and it works ok. Though I am also wondering what is the difference. Perhaps OSLog is just a bit newer.